# Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type '{ name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined;

Tags: reactjs, next.js, spotify, next-auth

I have a session value from next auth useSession hook ,

my session callback method is this :

```
async session({ session, token }) {
  console.log(token);
  session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
  session.user.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
  session.user.username = token.username;

  return session;
},
```

my session object is in a .js file and it has the properites : accesstoken , refreshtoken , username

if i try to use the value from the use session hook :

```
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  console.log(session?.user?.accessToken!);
```

i get the mentioned error , any help ?
my use session is in a tsx file and my next auth is in a js file if that matters

Answer (score 1):

The way I went around it was to overwrite the session type.

First, define a custom User type and Session Type like this:

```
export type UserType = {
   accessToken : string
   refreshToken : string
   username :  string
}


export type SessionType = {
  data: {
    expires  : string
    jwt : string
    user: UserType
  }
  status: "loading" | "authenticated" | "unathenticated"
}
```

Then in the .ts file import and use it like this.

```
  const {data, status}  = useSession() as SessionType
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ".ts" file where useSession custom hook available
there you might have created an Interface for user Object like below

```
Interface user {
  name: String,
  email: String
}
```

I think you have to add "accessToken" property in the user interface
If I am not wrong, so your final interace might be look like below code snippet.

```
Interface user {
 name: String,
 email: String,
 accessToken: String
}
```